# Web Audio oscillators unexpectedly glide from one frequency to another in Chrome

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The behavior I'm about to describe happens in Chrome 44, but does *not* happen in Firefox 40.

If you create an oscillator, set it to a frequency of 220 Hz, and then change the frequency to 440 Hz a second later, you can hear a distinct portamento effect: instead of changing instantly from 220 to 440, the oscillator *glides* from the original frequency to the new one.

The code below illustrates this phenomenon:

```js
var ac = new AudioContext();

var osc = ac.createOscillator();
osc.connect( ac.destination );

osc.type = 'sawtooth';

osc.frequency.value = 220;
osc.start( 0 );

window.setTimeout( function() {
    osc.frequency.value = 440;
}, 1000 );

window.setTimeout( function() {
    osc.stop( 0 );
}, 2000 );
```

I've examined the docs for the OscillatorNode object, and there's no mention of this behavior.

I've also scoured Google, and (surprisingly) I can't find any other mentions of this phenomenon.

What's going on? This doesn't seem like proper behavior. If I wanted the frequency to *glide*, I'd use the [linearRampToValueAtTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) method. Setting the frequency directly to a specific value should just...do that.

Is this just a bug? I know this API is still in flux, but this seems pretty blatant to be a bug - this wouldn't pass the most cursory testing. But I also can't imagine that Google would implement it this way *deliberately*.

Most importantly: is there a workaround?

Comment: It works "correctly" in Firefox, this is a webkit issue, so this also works with Opera and Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a bug.

I can't find anything in the spec that says direct assignment of `value` on an `AudioParam` should do any kind of interpolation.

It's possible that it's gone unnoticed because typically people probably modify the value using automation methods. Which brings me to your question of workarounds...

If you actually wanted an explicit delay, you can just do this (notice there's no `setTimeout`).

```
// change the value to 440Hz 1 second from now
osc.frequency.setValueAtTime( 440, ac.currentTime + 1 );
```

If you want to be able to change the frequency immediately (say, in response to a user action), you can just do this:

```
osc.frequency.setValueAtTime( 440, 0 );
```

Hope that helps.

By the way, you should consider filing an issue for this (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you! That workaround works for me. I probably should have thought of that myself, but...y'know. I'll try to remember to file a bug report tomorrow. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. For what it's worth, the behavior is present in Chrome Canary as well (Chrome 47) – which is a bit surprising. I usually don't see Web Audio bugs stick around for that long.

Comment: By the way, why do people typically modify the value using automation methods? Is it to keep the timing tight? (I imagine that firing changes manually at the time they're needed isn't as precise/reliable as scheduling them in advance with setValueAtTime() and the like. But in cases where you're responding to user input - e.g., an incoming MIDI event, or a parameter change via an in-browser control - you really have no choice.)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I could have worded that better. What I meant was "rather than using a timeout, people typically use automation methods for scheduling changes in the future" – for pretty much the exact reason you mentioned – super-precise timing. For immediate changes, directly assigning to `value` is typical and *should* work the way you'd expect.

Comment: `setValueAtTime` doesn't work for me on chrome ( 55.0.2883.21). it keeps the default freq, 440.

Answer (score 4):

This is the built-in "dezippering" effect, which the working group has gone back and forth on several times.  As of June, the WG finally decided to remove dezippering (status: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/76).  So yeah, this is a Chrome "bug" - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=496282).  Until it's fixed, use setValueAtTime(), as Kevin suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Chris. I ran across a mention of dezippering while looking in to this, but could only find it used in reference to GainNode – so didn't want to make the leap that maybe it was also used for Oscillators.

Comment: Yeah, it currently happens for .value on all AudioParams.